# using boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp header in Code::Blocks with c++

Tags: c++, build, header, codeblocks

I learn to code with C++. I need to use header, called boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp.
I looked for information, how to use headers with C++, but all this information included downloading file in your local device and then use 1) project->build options; 2) "search directories"; 3) "compilers" sub tab.

with this header I got confused - when opening this link: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp

i see plenty of other hyperlinks in this header file, such as:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_legacy_io.hpp"

#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp"
#endif // USE_DATE_TIME_PRE_1_33_FACET_IO

#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/time_parsers.hpp"
```

How such headers are actually used?
I tried import header with URL, but it did not work.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono if you need to do time stuff? Or are you learning how to use external libraries? In any case to use boost you would need to install it on your local system. Just browsing hyperlinks is not going to work. What OS and development environment are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889949/how-to-install-boost-libraries-with-codeblocks

Comment: I need to use one code, where this header is included. I use Code::Blocks and Windows 10

Comment: Seems someone else already made this: https://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/configure-codeblocks-boost-libraries-windows-linux/
A good skill to learn is how to find information on the web, in this case I just used google with "install boost time in codeblocks" and this was the 3rd link in the list.

Comment: did not work for me, thank you

Comment: Now I look how to do same in VSCode. i have this boost_1_77_0 downloaded and unzipped, but any good manual will be appreciated